# Unable to call my controller method via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this method in my controller:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static List<List<GraphData>> GetData()
{
    List<List<GraphData>> result = new List<List<GraphData>>();
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["GraphSensorData"] != null)
    {
        result = (List<List<GraphData>>)HttpContext.Current.Session["GraphSensorData"];
        return result;
    }
    else 
        return null;
}
```

I set a breakpoint to it but the following ajax doesn't call it at all:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/MainPage/GetData',
        data: {},
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data){
            //some logic
        }
    )};
```

I want to set a watch to data so I can see what I got in order to manipulate that data further but success doesn't fire.

Comment: check url. I think it must be `url: '/MainPage.aspx/GetData',` or something like this. You could try use something like this `window.location.href.split("?")[0] + '/GetData';` for url if you make ajax call from same controller, that GetData exists

Comment: What does Fiddler (or network tab in dev tools) say?

Answer (score 3):

Remember, you are not in Web Forms here, but ASP.NET MVC.

If you want an ASP.NET MVC controller method to be invoked via Ajax:

- The method should not be `static`
- You don't need to use attributes to say it's a web method, instead you return a `JsonResult`.

I'm thinking something like this would work:

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    List<List<GraphData>> result = new List<List<GraphData>>();
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["GraphSensorData"] != null)
    {
        result = (List<List<GraphData>>)HttpContext.Current.Session["GraphSensorData"];
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else return Json(new object(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, now the method is being called and result is being filled with data, but my ajax success is not firing :/ Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("ACTION NAME","CONTROLLER NAME")',
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data){
        //some logic
    }
)};
```

for the url part please use correct Action Name and Controller Name